# MySupportMapFragment not show location name as per google map Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, supportmapfragment

I am facing the issue when google map implement with MySupportMapFragment it's show location name in English language only as per given below image

[image]

But I want it as per below image(location name with English & Local Language)

[image]

My java code

```
mSupportMapFragment = (MySupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.maps_fragment);

mSupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        if (googleMap != null) {
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
            map = googleMap;
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(2));
        }
    }
});
```

My xml code

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/maps_fragment"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_174sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp" />
```

If one of you can give me any suggestion on how to fix my problem I will love to hear it. Thank you!

Comment: Probably just a matter of zoom. Try different zoom.

Comment: I have already tried full zoom